# Logs missing and empty message when forwarding syslog from macOS

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, syslog, asl

I have tried the syslog forwarding configuration as mentioned in splunk document, But on the syslog server I not getting all logs generated in macOS and also there is no Syslog content (message) in some logs like the following one, I am not getting any useful information when forwarded as Syslog . But In console I am able to view all logs.

https://wiki.splunk.com/Community:HowTo_Configure_Mac_OS_X_Syslog_To_Forward_Data

```
<6>Mar 19 10:46:05 catalinas-iMac diagnosticd[531]: New connection from peer 1663
<5>Mar 19 10:46:05 catalinas-iMac analyticsd[162]:
<5>Mar 19 10:46:05 catalinas-iMac analyticsd[162]:
<5>Mar 19 10:46:05 catalinas-iMac analyticsd[162]:
<5>Mar 19 10:46:05 catalinas-iMac analyticsd[162]:
<5>Mar 19 10:46:05 catalinas-iMac analyticsd[162]:
```

Can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Did you configure Splunk to listen on port 514 (you *shouldn't*, but you *can*)? What version of Splunk? While Splunk is working on improvements to the [macOS UF](https://ideas.splunk.com/ideas/EID-I-562), have you tried any of the suggestions from https://community.splunk.com/t5/Archive/Mac-OS-X-Sierra-How-to-get-all-logs-from-the-Unified-Log/td-p/347695?

Comment: I have not configured splunk in my syslog server. I have configured a syslog receiver in my server @ port 514 . I want to get all logs to be forwarded to my server . I tried configuring in syslog.conf also . is there any other configuration that need to be changed in MAC so that I can get all logs

Answer (score 0):

In googling this exact question (ie forwarding syslog on macOS to a syslog collector), I see several *other* posts referencing the now-out-of-date Splunk wiki link

For example: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1860034-forwarding-syslog-from-mac-os-x-to-syslog-server

This post indicates that you need to look at `/etc/asl.conf`, as logging has changed in more-recent versions of macOS - https://www.unixtutorial.org/syslog-and-asl-in-macos

There's also this aging, Graylog-related question on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/295947/4642) asking about how to collect macOS logs

The Apple manpage for asl is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/asl.3.html

And now, it *appears* the Unified Logger has replaced ASL: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Archive/Mac-OS-X-Sierra-How-to-get-all-logs-from-the-Unified-Log/m-p/347695

Based on all of this, it would seem the *current* "best" way to get logs of macOS systems to some centralized source (be it a "traditional" syslog collector, Splunk, etc) is with a scripted process that runs-through what's been locally collected in the last X period (maybe e just since last run), and sends it on to wherever you want it to go

Comment: Thank you response. As of now I don't have option to use script or universal forwarder as like in splunk. I checked the asl.conf man pages and tried different configuration  but as i said previously only for some logs the message is hidden or I think It may be due to ASL storing logs in binary format.
Also found that the ASL would take the configuration for each subsystem from plist files in /Library/LaunchAgents/ and /System/Library/LaunchDaemons. Could you please help me on how to configure those plist files.

Comment: @UserG - I'd suggest asking the plist question separately (and, possibly, on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) ), as it's *probably* a mostly-separate topic